# Case where fetch="join" gives duplicate resuls

Tags: hibernate

I have an Address class type, which has a collection of Employees (who work there).

The mapping from the class type to Hibernate of Address contains:

```
<set
    name="employees"
    inverse="true"
    lazy="true"
    fetch="join"
>
```

Also, there are 5 Address instances, and at each Address there are 5 Employee's working.

In the application,

```
org.hibernate.Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Address.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("zipcode", "%Work"));
List<Address>addresses=criteria.list();
```

Now addresses is a list of 25 addresses (each with 5 Employee's), every address is 5 times repeated. Why is this? This is my question.

If in the hibernate mapping of Address,

```
<set
    name="employees"
    inverse="true"
    lazy="false"
    fetch="select"
>
```

then is is OK, addresses has 5 entries,and each entry has a collection of 5 Employee's.

Comment: @dpawel09 is correct about the solution to your problem, but I'm curious why you have `lazy=true` *and* `join=fetch` on the Set? Both are conflicting ("only fetch association when requested" and "fetch everything using a JOIN statement when the root entity is fetched").

Comment: lazy is there because I also set it to false sometimes, and I thought lazy=true is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding DISTINCT to your query: `criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);`

Join fetch adds JOIN statement to query where fetch type select used additional SELECT to retrieve relation data, see: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching